# Can we render same route using navigator in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I have a view, lets say **DynamicView**. I am trying to push the **same** view(DynamicView)in navigator with different params.

```
this.props.navigator.push({
    component: DynamicView,
    params: {} //Different params
})
...
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(DynamicView)
```

**DynamicView** is connected with the redux flow. But I cannot access the latest state in the pushed component.

I want to know, whether is this the right thing to do? If yes, how can i access the latest state in the pushed component which is same as parent. If no, then is there any other approach to create the new route dynamically.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

**React Native v0.40**

Answer (score 3):

A React Navigation navigator, such as a StackNavigator for example, can easily support that. As [confirmed here](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/2533) by the creator of React Navigation.

So say you're doing some [basic navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/intro/basic-app) using a StackNavigator.
You would do something like this:

```
export const SimpleApp = StackNavigator({
  MyDynamicView: { screen: DynamicView }
  ... other routes ...
});
```

And then, from your React components (including the DynamicView component) you can navigate to the `MyDynamicView` route as many times as you want, with different params:

```
navigation.navigate('MyDynamicView, { username: 'John' })
```

or

```
navigation.navigate('MyDynamicView, { username: 'John2' })
```

Comment: ohh, I am happy that i am on the right path as suggested in link you have shared. Thank you.
But my dynamic component is connected with the redux store. Suppose if there are two same components loaded with different set of data, and if I am changing the state of set2 data which is on the last component in the stack, it is not taking up the changes. Only first dynamic component is getting the updated data.